# Use headphone+microphone ports for 2.1 sound

Tags: sound

I have a laptop with a headphone and microphone port based on the following sound card: `00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)`

Recently some 2.1 speakers found their way in to my possession, as these things do. I'm not using them for much at the moment but while we're moving house (we're going to be staying with friends for a week or two) I'd like to be able to have some decent sound, even if it's only 2.1.

Given that the laptop only has two ports and one of those is a microphone, I wondered if there's any way that I can re-purpose the microphone port and turn it into LFE port for the subwoofer. I'm *sure* I've seen this done before a while back (it was probably when I used Windows, all those years ago). I realise being able to do this is hardware specific.

Failing that, does anybody know a nice (***cheap!***) USB sound card that Ubuntu will cope with being plugged in and unplugged while running, and will give me 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to change the internal connections with [HDA Analyzer](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer), although it looks a bit daunting, and I couldn't find any good documentation for it. It has a "Graph" button which shows the circuitry, and you can hover and right click there, but finding out what you should connect to what looks like it's going to be a lot of trial and error.

It's also in a PPA, see http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.alsa.devel/85051/match=hda+analyzer.